# Java pattern matcher for the file

Tags: java

I have used following java pattern for the file **'ecd_pg2_cr_20120311_01.requests.xml.pgp'**

And my pattern matcher is: **'ecd_pg2*.requests.xml.pgp'**

But it's unable to find out the matches, any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
matcher =
            FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getPathMatcher("glob: ecd_pg2*.requests.xml.pgp");
```

Comment: Hi Pablo, unfortunately we use JDK1.4 so not latest version:)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `ecd_pg2.*\\.requests\\.xml\\.pgp`  instead of `ecd_pg2*.requests.xml.pgp` . Your expression essentially looks for strings for the form, ecd_pg2.requests.xml.pgp , ecd_pg22.requests.xml.pgp , ecd_pg222.requests.xml.pgp , ecd_pg222.requests.xml.pgp .